# What co-ordinate system is this data in, and how to convert it to lat-lon?

Tags: coordinates, gis, coordinate-systems

I've been sent some data, which relates to some locations in London, as follows:

```
x           y
-42,685.84  6,710,078.43
-42,746.62  6,710,143.38
-42,727.80  6,710,068.28
```

I cannot work out what co-ordinate system this is supposed to be. The data has apparently come from MapInfo.

They don't seem to be UTM ([converter](http://awsm-tools.com/geo/utm-to-geographic), and [grid](http://www.dmap.co.uk/utmworld.htm)), or at least, if I try a UTM converter, the location comes out nowhere near London. Perhaps I am using the converter wrongly.

Ultimately I'd like to convert these, whatever they are, to latitude-longitudes.

Comment: Perhaps [EPSG:27700](http://epsg.io/27700)?

Comment: I think it's better to ask the data provider, otherwise you'll have to go the brute force and it's not so reliable. This is the page describes how to do it in ArcGIS: http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/29129

Comment: Where you given a .prj file with it?  Or some kind of text describing the coordinate system?